# How to change multiple values in the array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array created with a for loop that has 50 values.

```
var array = [];
array [0] = {
selection : 0
}
var number = 1;

for (i = 0; i < 50; i++){
array[i].selection = number;
number ++;}
```

How to change the value for the `array[i-20].selection`? I don't want to use array[30].selection

It usually works if use `array[i-1].selection` or `array[i+1].selection` but doesn't work if use anything greater than one.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you expect that any index other than `0` has an object with a `selection` property?

Comment: You are assigning the `{selection: 0}` object just to the first array index. The other 50 are empty. How do you expect to set `selection` property if there's no objects in other indexes?

Answer (score 0):

You wanted Array of Objects and not Array with single Object, right ?

```js
var array = [];
var number = 1;

fillFrom(3, 1); // should push instead of setting and start from zero but ;-)

var res = '<table width=1><tr><td>' + JSON.stringify(array).replace(/,/g, ',<br>') + '</td>';

fillFrom(0, -49);

res += '<td>' + JSON.stringify(array).replace(/,/g, ',<br>') + '</td></tr></table>';
document.body.innerHTML = res;

function fillFrom(start, number) {
  for (i = start; i < 50; i++) {
    if (array[i] === undefined) array[i] = {
      selection: number
    };
    else array[i].selection = number;
    number++;
  }
}
```

Comment: There are 2 versions yet. Older simple under link edited above.